# What is Correlation ID in Mule 4 and How to set it at starting of flow in variables till end of the flow. What is datatype of correlationID

Tags: mule, mule4

I am new to a mule, need to know about correlationId in Mule 4 to track the job.
What is Correlation ID in Mule 4 and How to set it at the starting of flow in variables till end of the flow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `correlationId` is a unique value that is assigned automatically when an event is started, at the beginning of a flow. It can be obtained from the [predefined variable](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/dataweave-variables-context) `#[correlationId]`.

You can think of it as the identifier of a [Mule Event](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/about-mule-event).

Answer (score -2):

Technically correlation ID is a String. It is generates automatically and is immutable.
Technically you don't need it at all. Maybe for some weird file names so they are unique. But it could be done in many other ways.

It is used by Mule for cluster and other synchronizations. As well as to tag in the log files to distinguish between sessions.

Suggestion - leave it alone and don't even think about it.

Comment: I need it to track throughout the job. So that if a job is successful, it will return correlationId.